# What legendary shiny pokemon are legitimately obtainable as of Sword/Shield?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-sword-shield

Within a few months, Nintendo will launch the first DLC of Pokemon Sword / Shield. As I understand it, in that DLC, they will introduce all the remaining legendary pokemon.

One of my goals is to try to get every legendary Pokemon in their normal and shiny form. But some of them are not legitimately available in shiny form.

I know that the first three legendary birds and Mewtwo are legal, since in *Pokemon Let's Go* you can get them by doing soft reset. But I'm not sure about other legendaries.

Therefore, I would like to know which are legitimately available as shiny (or which are not), and how to obtain them.

Comment: The legendary-themed DLC is the *second* one, The Crowned Tundra, not the first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some Legendary and Mythical Pokemon cannot be shiny. As of the release of generation 8, these are: Victini, Keldeo, Meloetta, Hoopa, Volcanion, Cosmog and Cosmoem, Magearna, Zeraroa, Zacian, Zamazenta and Eternatus.

These Pokemon cannot be legally shiny under any circumstance. That aside, the following Pokemon are also "Shiny Locked". This means that when they are encountered in-game in these generations, they are hardcoded to never be shiny. They can however still be shiny through events or encounters from other games.

Event Pokemon have their shiny status predetermined if received through Mystery Gift. For Pokemon that have in-game events associated with them, reference the list below.

**Generation 5**

- Victini
- Zekrom
- Reshiram

**Generation 6**

- Articuno
- Zapdos
- Moltres
- Xerneas
- Yveltal
- Zygarde
- Kyogre
- Groudon
- Deoxys

**Generation 7**

- Tapu Koko
- Tapu Lele
- Tapu Bulu
- Tapu Fini
- Cosmog
- Solgaleo
- Lunala
- Nihilego (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Buzzwole (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Pheromosa (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Xurkitree (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Kartana (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Guzzlord (Only in Sun and Moon, not locked in Ultra Sun and Ultra Moon)
- Necrozma

**Generation 8**

- Starters (gift only, can still be bred as shiny)
- Charmander (gift only, can be encountered as shiny or bred)
- Gigantamax Pikachu (gift only, can be encountered as shiny)
- Gigantamax Eevee (gift only, can be encountered as shiny)
- Toxel (gift only, can be encountered as shiny or bred)
- Zacian
- Zamazenta
- Eternatus

**Let's Go Pikachu and Eevee**

- Partner Pokemon

[Source](https://www.serebii.net/games/shiny.shtml)

Comment: With the release of the Isle of Armor, it is now possible to get shiny gigantamax pokemon that have been hatched from EGGs with the power of soup.

Answer (score 1):

you can basically get a legit shiny of any pokemon in go once the transferring method becomes available, that means every pokemon pre gen 6 (granted they release shiny victini, shiny meloetta, shiny keldo, and next week shiny genesect) sorry my spelling might be off a little, and I really don’t know if they will let you transfer mythicals and legendaries

(Also no illegitimate shiny mythicals, besides keldo and the new one are confirmed)

Answer (score 1):

With the Crown Tundra, you can do Dynamax adventures and obtain all the the shiny legendaries from gen 1-7 but not Gen 8+ or the DLC exclusive legendaries.

Comment: Obtaining “all” shiny legendaries through dynamax adventure is not fully accurate. While you have a chance to obtain shinies of the Gen 3 Regis (as well as Gen 8 Regis) through parts of the story, they are not included in dynamax adventures